# Floating problems with html li

Tags: html, css

I have this site here: http://dev.jmret.com/index.php but i have a problem on the content page i have two `<li>` underneath each other and one floating next to it. But it only floats next to the second. How would i make i float next to the first `<li>`?

So it looks something like this.
CSS (what i am using currently):

```
.sub-info {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 67%;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    margin-right: 1%;
    padding-left: 3%;
    float: none;
}
.sub-info2 {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 26%;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    /* margin-right: 1%; */
    float: left;
    /* padding-right: 5%; */
    padding-left: 1%;
}
```

So what i need to do is make it so that the 3 `<li>` stack correctly, how can i make this happen in css?

Many thanks

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Comment: Hi, I added the CSS i am using currently in order to show how it is styled at the moment

Comment: You also need to add the relevant HTML, as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to wrap your `ul` into a div, and then make it float next to it. First change the css to this :

```
.sub-info {
    display: inline;
    position: relative;
    width: 95%;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    margin-right: 1%;
    padding-left: 3%;
    float: left;
}
```

then in your `li.body-section`, wrap the two first `ul`'s into a `div` and leave the last `ul` outside like this :

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <ul></ul>
   <ul></ul>
</div>
<ul></ul>
```

and add the css :

```
.wrapper {
   float : left;
}
```

I believe you wanted something like this :
[image]

Comment: Thanks you very much this worked with a few adjustments (i had to set the width of the div)

Comment: First <ul> isn't closing. Should be <ul></ul>. Tried to edit, but apparently edits have be 6 characters or more. Useful! :)

Comment: @TomKentell woops, typo ! Edited :)

Comment: @Deckerz you're welcome ! The div width will be set according to the .sub-info width. That's why i put 95% in the css :)

Comment: Ah thanks for some reason the div width wasnt being set.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your `ul` containing the right column has `display: block;`.

Change to `display: inline-block;` on the `ul` containing `.sub-info2` and remove the `width` on `.sub-info2`.

Like this (inline styling, but you'll get the point):

```
<ul style="display: inline-block;">
     <li class="sub-info2" style="width: auto">
          <ul>
               <li class="text tablet">
```

Comment: That doesn't work for me, it moves the right side column into the center and makes it tiny. width